# Access property that might not exist on a type and get undefined

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code:

```
type A = {
    x: number;
} | {
    y: number;
}

const a = { x: 0 } as A;
const b = a.x;
```

And get the following error:

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'A'.
  Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ y: number; }'.ts(2339)
```

`b` is of type `any`

I understand, that `x` on `a` might not exist, but in normal Javascript, when accessing a property that does not exist, you always get `undefined`. Therefore, I would expect TS to return me `number | undefined`.

---

An even more simple example:

```
const bar = ({}).foo;
```

`bar` should be undefined, but is any.

---

How can I tell Typescript to give me `undefined` instead of `any` and an error when accessing a property which might not exist?

Comment: The issue is that object types in TS are not closed or sealed.  Excess properties do not invalidate a type, as required for interface/class hierarchies to also be type hierarchies.  So as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXzpVm) demonstrates, `a.x` could truly be anything unless all union members of `A` are explicit about what happens when you access the `x` property, like `{x: number, y?: never} | {x?: never, y: number}`.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer post; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that explains why I get `any` instead of `undefined` and also why fixing this isn't really possible. Shouldn't Typescript also have the same problem with in? E.g. using `"x" in a` to find out what type of `A` my variable is. Thank you :)

Comment: It "should" if you care about soundness above all, but the TS team has decided that people using `"x" in a` this way know what they're doing in a way that I guess people using `a.x` do not.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065#issuecomment-643826453) in a related github issue for example. ‍♂️.   I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (it might not be until tomorrow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Object types in TypeScript can have more properties than mentioned in their declarations**

Object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extensible* and not *closed* or *sealed*. A value of a type can have more properties than are specified in that type.  Just because a type doesn't mention a property, it doesn't mean that a value of that type is necessarily missing that property.  In other words, object types in TypeScript cannot be made "*exact*", as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

For example:

```
interface Y {
  y: number;
}
```

We know that a value of type `Y` must have a `y` property of type `number`:

```
let y: Y;
y = {}; // error, Property 'y' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Y'.
y = { y: "oops" }; // error, Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
y = { y: 123 }; // okay
```

And it might even seem that other properties are prohibited.  After all, if you assign an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) with extra properties to `y`, you get an error:

```
y = { x: "oops", y: 123 }; // error!
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type 'Y'
```

But this error is not happening because `Y` doesn't *allow* an `x` property; it's because the object literal is being assigned directly to something which will *forget* about the `x` property.  That is, this [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) is more of a linter rule than a type system check, and it specifically targets object literals and not all values:

```
const xy = { x: "oops", y: 123 };
y = xy; // okay, no error
```

The above is accepted because `xy` will remember the `x` property, so it's accessible *somewhere*.  When you assign `y = xy`, `xy` is just a value and not an object literal, so there's no error.

Indeed, allowing excess properties is required for [extending interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) to work as expected:

```
interface XY extends Y {
  x: string;
}

const val: XY = xy; // okay
```

If you couldn't add properties to types without invalidating those types, a lot of interface and class hierarchies would no longer be type hierarchies, and that would break both [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and JavaScript native classes like DOM elements.

---

**Therefore a property not mentioned in every member of a union could hold any value whatsoever if it exists**

In your example you have a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) equivalent to

```
type A = { x: number; } | Y;
```

As we showed above, a value can be of type `Y` while also having properties `Y` doesn't know about.  Specifically, the `XY` type has an `x` property of type `string`.  So the following assignment is accepted:

```
const a: A = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { x: 123 } : val; // okay
```

And now we immediately hit a problem with checking the `x` property of `a`.  If the compiler allowed us to assume that `a.x` were either `number` or `undefined`, we could write

```
a.x?.toFixed()
```

with no warning.  And you'd get a runtime error because `a.x` is a `string` and not a `number`, and has no `toFixed()` method.  So you get a compiler error

```
try {
  a.x?.toFixed(); // error!
  //~ <-- Property 'x' does not exist on type 'A'.
  //a.x is of type any
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e) // a.x.toFixed is not a function
}
```

saying that `x` does not exist on `A`, and the type of `a.x` is inferred to be [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  This is the best the compiler can do (well, it should probably be the more type-safe [`unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) instead of `any`, but `unknown` is a more recent addition to the type system than `any` and it would be a big breaking change to do that now).

If you want to safely access a property of a union, it should be mentioned in every member of that union.  If you intend it to be missing or `undefined`, you should say so by making it an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) property of type `undefined` or [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

```
type A = { x: number, y?: never } | { x?: never, y: number };
```

Then the compiler will prevent you from assigning an `XY` to an `A`:

```
let a: A;
a = val; // error!
```

And then `a.x` will definitely be `number` or `undefined`:

```
a = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { x: 123 } : { y: 123 }; // okay
a.x?.toFixed(); // okay
```

---

**The TypeScript type system isn't fully sound so you could use the `in` operator if you want**

So there you go; you can't access properties of a union unless they are mentioned in every member of that union, because object types aren't exact, and the compiler will complain when you try to violate type safety.  Because type safety is very important.

But that can't be the whole story. [TypeScript Language Design Non-Goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #3 is

> Apply a sound or "provably correct" type system. Instead, strike a balance between correctness and productivity.

There are [intentionally places in TypeScript where type safety is ignored in favor of usability](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness). These places were chosen by human beings, for human reasons.  There might be some objective data showing that certain soundness holes lead to fewer problems than you'd get if you fixed them, but ultimately this is at the discretion of the TS language design team.

So, one such unsoundness (as you mentioned in the comments) is the [use of the `in` operator to narrow unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
if ("x" in a) {
  a.x.toFixed(2); // no compiler error
} else {
  a.y.toFixed(2); // no compiler error
}
```

By checking that `a` has an `x` key, the compiler narrows `a` from `A` to `{x: number}`, and lets you access `a.x.toFixed()` with no warning.  But this has the same problem as shown above, and indeed, you can get the compiler to agree to this and then hit a runtime error whan `a.x` turns out to be a `string`.

And the only answer I can give for why this happens is that the TypeScript team has decided that it's better to allow this than to forbid it.  As mentioned in a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065#issuecomment-643826453) on a [microsoft/TypeScript#39065](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065), a declined request to allow you to assume, as you originally thought, that properties of unions are either present or `undefined`:

> The "lack" of this feature is very much intentional; this pattern is not safe to use because object types aren't closed, so the existence of a value in some property slot is really not a solid indication that anything correct is happening. The `in` operator is granted an exception to this because there's nothing else you might be intending to do with the `in` operator.

So another approach you could take is to use the `in` operator as shown above before accessing the property, with the assumption that edge cases like `XY` will not show up in practice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQE1UG9itQTwC5UwBXAWwCNYBuYAX2GABsoIDj079UBebejVQB6YalgwA9jAA0qAApSADrAg8A5PnWoQAZ1Tk9u8AHMdYVGpWp1Wetsql2MKAEdSIFwBNzl-NfV0dQA6YB5+LA5UACJJSSVdaNRBETEJaTkAFX80dV0IGFNtPRJJdgRdYxMwBEpWS0k-ALIqWBCwvmwogEYAJgBmZKFRVEkAawR8JnCugA9iWPjEuSJUPsGUkfSYAEJgEbwAeUoAKygkdmYQaBgEZgNJ0bBmHl0VJBA4HjGwSQB3CxKZSqEBQXRyBBgHzqWbaLySMGldhQWZ6djgJq5IJMJCSMD5VCzGaReYxOIJaIrYjrIYdfhE4ZicaTOS-cQwKQwJjgG6IFCoAAamBR0Ch+kwODwpPyhTAJjojGAuPx7AAbndiELOgzUqMJlNgFY0ABBTok4gtagwIT0VAAHwwdCVeIJCGIpv4AFkEBAABbBW5QyTkAAUAEpUAAeVAABmCAFZUAB+ObUgbJVDEdXMRlRgC0ecsvpKulISBQUC8+moSAQpF0aC1IqgYowqEhPmFs1FVdQxpxLvYlE6CGCs1zkYLRZKJUKJl9EBe7bAPBD5Em1B07F0vskpGYPk3pDAP3+YAjHaRJAoVvtqGPXigcHAlaYBR4kvbY6TwQgkgAYiAsyVuGubbHseCiAAfvmhaKPEqgaLCqDwoivzIqiBJ4piNhBMEIYDP0ACcYa4Kko6zDo+iSHAOGQlMtq1hASC+qgIZQBGn7KrokisMEzCSCY7ERiMFG-gBQGVlRV4IKgcDHhcIB4gwTDADU5BgkoyBoIBlE4GRRp9mahIWjesArEmFpQKqsAZg6JKWSQ1nmVElq2YITB4Kw5TunQeCyfw2ZgRy0gQe2nTen6AYdsG4ZRrGCbJqmazpraxCRKsNKbEy+qeV+sw-n+ukgWGubMgaKmGjAH55Z8bHRLMSQYggnFkf5Y7icVXgEaVupsri5BKCArAwOynJkbaUDMA22BtV++CdZJ3W9L1Iz9cGQ0jWN0gTUwjE+ixbEcbNeDcbxUD8YJwkMEAA)